# Electron - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, json, electron

relatively new to electron area:

I tried a few method to solve this issue such as using `./` instead of `/` or adding `"homepage" :` in packaging.json and still won't work.

I was trying to import these two

```
<script src="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js"></script>
<link href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

my json:

```
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage":"./",
  "main": "main.js",
   ....
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Infomation Board </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css" />
    <script src="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js"></script>
    <link href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  ..
```

And when I run debug, I get either of these errors:

```
GET file:///C:/node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

 GETfile:///C:/Users/whatd/OneDrive/Desktop/Amazon%20Verson%202/src/directories/node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

directory:

[image: directory]

how would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Did u install gridstack using npm?

Comment: Like with the `styles.css`, you could provide a correct relative path: e.g. `../../node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js`

Comment: @DeepakMukka Yes i did and as for snwflk I tried and still throw me the same errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `"homepage":` line in your `package.json` file is a React thing. If you are not using React then you can remove the `"homepage":` line.

The `"main":` line in your `package.json` file is the entry point of your Electron app. Therefore, if the js file that will kick things off is `"main.js"` then `"main": "main.js"` is correct.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  ...
}
```

If you are creating your info-board window in your `main.js` file then you would do so like this.

`main.js`

```js
// Electron module(s).
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Node module(s).
const nodePath = require('path');

// Declare window (no garbage collect).
let infoBoardWindow;

// Application is now ready to start.
electronApp.on('ready', () => {

  // Create the info-board window.
  infoBoardWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: { 
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  // Load the info-board window.
  infoBoardWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, './src/directories/infoboard.html'))
  .then(() => { infoBoardWindow.show(); })
});
```

Now, to reference both the gridstack css and js files in your `infoboard.html` file use relative paths (`./`, `../`), not an absolute path (`/`). IE: You need to step-up 2 directory levels to get access to the `node_modules` directory.

`infoboard.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Infomation Board </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" />
    <script src="../../node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  ..
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening when having `<base href="/">` in the index.html, just replace it by `<base href="./">`

Or if you have any other url, use relative URL by adding `./` at beginning.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!